# Referencing a global variable from a task kills my gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have a minimalistic `build.gradle` file with a `good` and `bad` task. I would like to understand why does this not work, giving me a strange error:

```
def owner = 1

task('bad') {
    doLast {
      println "My owner is, ${owner}"  
    }
}

task good {
    doLast {
        println 'This is good'
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'test\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> No signature of method: build_6t4ha87o2gnjb2kllhp0wwfpi$_run_closure1.doLast() is applicable for argument types: (build_6t4ha87o2gnjb2kllhp0wwfpi$_run_closure
1$_closure4) values: [build_6t4ha87o2gnjb2kllhp0wwfpi$_run_closure1$_closure4@33517a36]
Possible solutions: doCall(), doCall(java.lang.Object), collect(), collect(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

However simply removing the reference to `owner` from the println or even just renaming my global `owner` variable to `owner1` works. Looks like I am interfering with some gradle internals, but not exactly sure how.

I am using gradle 3.4 for this experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you imagined, `owner` is used internally. Specifically, it's used by the Groovy class [`Closure`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html).
You are inside a task with a defined `Closure` so, when you declare `owner` as `def`, the compiler doesn't know if you refer to your `owner` variable or to the converted get method [`getOwner()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#getOwner--) (that will be transformed in `owner`).

You can verify that a previous occurence is found in this way (after you have removed your owner declaration):

```
task verifyOwnerExistence {
    println "Owner exists: ${owner != null}"
}
```